# Using std string accessor with ostream operator <<

Tags: c++, string, overloading, iostream, accessor

If I create a class:

```
// First Example
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class my_class {
  std::string str;
public:
  my_class(const char* s = "") : str(s) {}

  operator const char* () const { return str.data(); } // accessor
};

my_class mc1{"abc"};
std::cout << mc1; // Calls the char* accessor and successfully writes "abc" to screen output.
```

If I modify the class thus:

```
// Second Example
class my_class {
  std::string str;
public:
  my_class(const char* s = "") : str(s) {}

  operator std::string () const { return str; } // accessor
};

my_class mc1{"abc"};
std::string mystring = mc1; // Calls the string accessor
std::cout << mystring; // Also successfully writes "abc" to screen output.
```

However, if I try to call:

```
std::cout << mc1;
```

I will get a page full of compilation errors that begin with:

> error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'my_class' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I can correct this error by adding to the second example class:

```
  friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, my_class& rhs) {
    os << rhs.str;
    return os;
  }
```

which I mostly cribbed from one of the suggested solutions to this problem.  But I don't understand why it is necessary using a string accessor but not a char* accessor.

I was expecting successful compilation and output of the value of mc1.str, OR I would have expected the same error trying to use the char* accessor function in the fist example.  Instead I received C2679 on the second example only.

UPDATE:  I see that using a cast operator in the ostream, e.g. `std::cout << (std::string)mc1;`, will explicitly invoke the string accessor and write the string to the screen.

Comment: The error accurately describes the problem. The stream class has no conversion from `my_class` to something it understands; the stream class doesn't know what to do with `my_class`. In other words, the stream class hasn't been programmed for `my_class` (obviously).  By providing a **friend** implementation, you are explicitly providing the conversion needed. The **friend** function gets called since its parameters match the statement

Comment: Thanks, @Scheff'sCat, for catching my copy errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because of how the functions are defined.

For the `const char*` case, the `operator <<` that `cout` has available for that is declared as:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
    operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, const char* s );
```

So, when the compiler analyzes `std::cout << mc1;`, it can deduce what `CharT` and `Traits` are from `cout`, and it finds `my_class::operator const char* ()` to convert `mc1` into a `const char*`, so overload resolution is successful and the code compiles.

When you switch to having `operator std::string ()` and use `std::cout << mc1;`, you now need to call the `std::string` overload for `operator <<`, which is declared as:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
    operator<<( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
                const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str );
```

In this overload, not only does the first parameter rely on the template parameters, but so does the second parameter.  This means the compiler is going to try and deduce the types of `CharT`, `Traits` and `Allocator` from `mc1` directly.  No conversion operators are considered during this step, and since `mc1` is not actually a `std::string`, deduction fails and you are left with no possible overloads, so the code fails to compile.

Comment: "No conversion operators are considered during this step [template resolution?]"  Is this just a rule?  I appreciate that basic_string is a template, but I would have thought that the typedef string was already resolved enough that the implicit conversion could invoke the accessor.  Is it that the compiler sees the my_class type and assigns it to CharT *first* before then goin on to determine that this doesn't actually work for purposes of writing to an ostream?  Trying to understand the general principle.

Comment: @user2871308 `std::cout << mc1;` is syntactic sugar for `operator <<(cout, mc1)`.  During template argument deduction the compiler analyzes the types of the parameters passed to the function and tries to deduce the template arguments from them.  `mc1` is not a `std::string`, so it can't deduce any parameters so the full deduction process fails and you are left with no function to be able to call.  *Is it that the compiler sees the my_class type and assigns it to CharT first before then goin on to determine that this doesn't actually work for purposes of writing to an ostream?* Pretty much.